# Proving set properties?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am stuck with proving that RHS = LHS. I don't know where to begin and how prove the questions below.

[image]

Comment: Try mutual subset inclusion to show equality via element-chasing proofs.

Comment: Try to prove that x belongs to LHS => x belongs to RHS which will imply that LHS is a subset of RHS. Then do the reverse thing which will imply RHS is a subset of LHS. Together these two proves that LHS = RHS.

Comment: now how do you prove that x belongs to LHS

Comment: First assume that x belongs to LHS and then show that if x belongs to LHS than x belongs to RHS as well. Then all x that belong to LHS will belong to RHS also which proves that x is either equal to or is a proper subset of RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A-B=A\cap B^c$, where $B^c$ denotes the complement of $B$. Using the *distributivity of the intersection of the union* $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cup C)$ and the associativity of $\cap$ and $\cup$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
(R\cup S)-T&=(R\cup S)\cap T^c=(R\cap T^c)\cup(S\cap T^c)=(R-T)\cup(S-T),\\
(R\cap S)-T&=(R\cap S)\cap T^c=R\cap(S\cap T^c)=R\cap(S-T).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Oh!!! complements, I had long forgotten them. Thankyou so much Mr. Algebraic Pavel

Comment: does this hold if these were multi sets